# I want a div sized 40mm X 40mm on any screen and independent of zoom?

Tags: jquery, html, css, size, viewport

So I need to display something on screen that has to measure 40mm by 40mm.
No matter what smartphone, screen and no matter what zoom level.
How is this possible?
I am coding in HTML5, CSS, Javascript and Jquery.
In other words if I measure with a real life ruler on the div, it should always be 40 by 40.

Comment: We appreciate if you show us what you did until now

Comment: I am building a simple web app.

Comment: Thank you so much,
I am coding a simple web app in html, Jquery.
If I can not find a solution to this sizing problem I will have to take a different approach.
I have only made a simple snippet for isolated testing purposes.
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
 #exactSize
  {
   
   width:40mm;
   height:40mm;
   background-color:red; 
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="exactSize">
  <p> 40 by 40</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You simply calculate how big a pixel would be in mm.
Take 40 and divide it by the result and then set that as `div` `height` and `width`.

`1px` should be around `0.264583333 mm`

That means:

`40mm = 151,1811025526691055781658023032 ~ 151,18px` width and height

The actual size of the pixel however depends on the dpi so it's hard to say it accurately.

To be more specific:

```
cm * 600 dpi / 2,54 = px // depends on your dpi
```

[Read more about DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Consider a road-side digital billboard. It's a few feet tall by a few feet more wide, but resolution might only be 250x150px or something. In this case, pixels might be .5" or something. You can't get the size of the pixels reported back. There's no way to do what you're asking to do.